# Notice: Undefined index: descripcion

Tags: php

I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: descripcion in C:\wamp\www\viver\public\products_ajax.php on line 47
```

My line 47 is:

```
 $desc_prod = ($productos['descripcion']!== NULL) ? $productos['descripcion'] : "";
```

I make a var_dump($productos) and get :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nombre_producto' => string 'Calabacin blanco' (length=16)
      'nombre_latin' => null
      'peso' => string '100.00' (length=6)
      'descatalogado' => string '0' (length=1)
      'dimensiones' => null
      'descripcion' => null
      'cantidad_stock' => string '100' (length=3)
      'precioVenta' => string '1.00' (length=4)
      'gama_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'proveedor_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I want to do, that when product is different NULL show the description

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot one dimension so try it with this:

(It's a multidimensional Array)

```
$productos[0]['descripcion']
```

So your code line should look like this:

```
$desc_prod = ($productos[0]['descripcion']!== NULL) ? $productos[0]['descripcion'] : "";
```